# Runtime of bubble/simple sort

Tags: sorting, data-structures, runtime, theory

In class, simple sort is used as like one of our first definitions of O(N) runtimes...

But since it goes through one less iteration of the array every time it runs, wouldn't it be something more along the lines of...

Runtime bubble= sum(i = 0, n, (n-i)) ?

And aren't only the biggest processes when run one after another counted in asymptotic analysis which would be the N iteration, why is by definition this sort not O(N)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of `1 + 2 + ... + N` is `N*(N+1)/2` ... (high school maths) ... and that approaches `(N^2)/2` as `N` goes to infinity.  Classic `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you (or your professor) got the notion that bubble sort is O(n). If your professor *had* a guaranteed O(n) sort algorithm, they'd be wise to try and patent it :-)

A bubble sort is, by it's very nature, O(n<sup>2</sup>).

That's because it has to make a full pass of the entire data set, to correctly place the first element.

Then a second pass of `N - 1` elements to correctly place the second. And a third pass of `N - 2` elements to correctly place the third.

And so on, effectively ending up with close to `N * N / 2` operations which, removing the superfluous `0.5` constant, is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of bubble sort is O(n^2).
When considering the complexity, only the largest expression is considered (but not the factor)